# Format pino file stream with pino-pretty

Tags: javascript, logging, fs, pinojs

I build my first logger for my discord .js bot.

Now I need help with this:

How can I format the output fs stream also with pino-pretty?
This is my code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pinoms = require('pino-multi-stream')

const date = new Date()

const prettyStream = pinoms.prettyStream({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true, translateTime: "SYS:standard", ignore: "hostname,pid" } });
var streams = [
    {stream: fs.createWriteStream(`logs/${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}-${date.getHours()}-${date.getMinutes()}.log`) },
    {stream: prettyStream }
]

var logger = pinoms(pinoms.multistream(streams))
module.exports = logger;
```

I've looked for some solutions but couldn't find anything.
Please help!

Comment: I had a similar problem meybe it is helpful for yours.
[my Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71158986/stream-into-file-using-destination-option-in-pino-multi-stream)

Answer (score 0):

we are using Pino multistream with pino pretty because pinoms are depreciated.

Comment: you should use comment section for suggestions.